# Simple one-page horizontal scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a very simple horizontal scrolling animation for a one-page site ([example](http://yaronschoen.com/)). I basically want one paragraph to be showing at a time, and clicking the left and right arrows will scroll horizontally to the previous and next paragraphs respectively.

I've been working on it, but I'm not exactly sure how to only have one paragraph shown at a time and how exactly I would go about switching between them (I understand that I would need to add `click` eventListeners to the arrows, but I'm not sure how I would make them work).

Here is what I've coded so far:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p id="slide1" class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p id="slide2" class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p id="slide3" class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <a id="prev">←</a>
    <a id="next">→</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

#prev, #next {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  color: #c2c2c2;
  transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
}

#prev:hover, #next:hover {
  background: #dedede;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prev {
  float: left;
}

#next {
  float: right;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
var next = document.getElementById('next');

prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Somehow make this go to the previous paragraph
});

next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Somehow make this go to the next paragraph
});
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/27nmow1x/embedded/result/) is a jsfiddle if that helps at all. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm currently not using jQuery with this, but I'm not opposed to it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that in the description! I'm actually not currently using jQuery with this, but I guess I'm not opposed to adding it in.

Answer (score 0):

So I did somethings to your fiddle to help you out.

Basically, I made a really simple transitioning code that I hope you'll understand. I wrote it with a couple comments so you'd know what was happening in the code.

If you just read it completely top to bottom without skipping, the comments should be very explanatory. What I did was find the id for all your sliders, and put them in an array. I set their styles using the `.style` acessor for html objects in javascript, and changed their "display" attribute. The next thing was the function, which simply offset the position and made the previous slider invisible and the newest one visible.

```
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
var next = document.getElementById('next');

// First I made a variable that contains all the sliders(paragraphs) you have. 
var slide1 = document.getElementById('slide1'),
    slide2 = document.getElementById('slide2'),
    slide3 = document.getElementById('slide3');

// Using these sliders, I placed them into a more convenient data collection, an array called sections
var sections = [slide1, slide2, slide3],
    sectionPosition = 0;// We had to give it an index, so we know what slider we're on

// In javascript, once you have saved an html object you can access it's "style" attributes with the .style accessor and change it like so
for( i = 1; i < sections.length; i ++ ){
       sections[i].style.display = "none";// make all sliders invisible   
}

slide1.style.display = "initial";// We're going to leave the first one in it's initial state


// Since we don't want to rewrite code, let's make a generic function that can do the switching for us -- also it's always good to use less ambiguis functions. 
var nextParagraph = function(change){
    var prevParagraph = sections[ sectionPosition ];// get the slide that's being changed

    // We want to increment or decrement the index by x amount, so lets make sure it loops through the index correctly staying within a correct range.
    sectionPosition = (sectionPosition + change) % sections.length;//% is a modulu operator used for cycling numbers 
    if( sectionPosition < 0 ){
        sectionPosition += sections.length;
    }
    // this line basically sets the previous one to inivisble and makes the current slide visible
    var currentParagraph = sections[ sectionPosition ];
    prevParagraph.style.display = "none";
    currentParagraph.style.display = "initial";
}

prev.addEventListener('click', function(){nextParagraph(-1);} );

next.addEventListener('click', function(){nextParagraph(1);});
```

Mind you I don't typically work with Java, but this is the simple form of what you want!

**I did** the very basics of what you want. I recommend that you try adding the following and see how you can accomplish it:

- Instead of hard coding your sliders into the array like I did, see if you can *(hint)* take *classes* of a slider and add all of them into an array.
- Animate your sliders (Jquery is a great thing to learn for things like this)

[Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/27nmow1x/4/)

Comment: I double the hard coding part, he is right. It limits scalability. If you have a lot of paragraphs, it will be a waste of time to write down all the ids. (my solution also hardcodes them for simplicity but it is bad practice)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already knew how to do most of this with JS, I was mostly struggling with animating it to slide horizontally. I appreciate you commenting it all out and explaining it well however.

Comment: I don't have the time right at the moment, but adding in the Jquery for sliding should not be too difficult. If that is what you were looking for in particular, I think you should just rephrase your question a bit differently and wait until someone has fully answered it. Though, next time I suggest highlighting the animation over the code(or something similar in similar questions). @sinanspd is more on track towards solving your problem, so if he were to change it a little bit more you'd have transitions too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it, it uses a slight hack with Jquery but I think it is shorter. ALSO PLEASE change the a elements to buttons. a elements are specifically meant to be used if you are redirecting to another page. If you are dynamically changing things on the page use buttons. There are so many reasons why you wouldnt want to use a

```
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

var i = 0;
var pArray=["#slide1", "#slide2", "#slide3"]

$("#next").click(function(){
    var j;
    if(i == 2){
        j = 0;
    }else{
        j= i+1;
    }
    $(pArray[i]).css("display", "none");
    $(pArray[j]).css("display", "block");
    i++;
    if(i == 3){
        i = 0;
    }
})

 $("#prev").click(function(){
    var j;
    if(i == 0){
        j = 2;
    }else{
        j= i - 1;
    }
    $(pArray[i]).css("display", "none");
    $(pArray[j]).css("display", "block");
    i--;
    if(i == -1){
        i = 2;
    }
})
  })

  </script>
```

Comment: This is shorter, but it also is just changing the css display, I was hoping more for learning how to do the horizontal scrolling.